# Транслитерация в VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic, .net, framework

Здравствуйте . Мне нужно проверить имя файла на наличие кириллицы , если такие символы там есть , то заменить их на латинские. Вопрос в том - **есть ли что-то похожее в NET библиотеках , либо делать вручную ?**

Comment: Я лет 10 назад писал на VBA макрос под Word2000 для транслитерации кириллицы в латиницу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.NET очень поверхностный язык, мало вероятно, что подобные библиотеки есть.
Вот функция, правда она возвращает только в нижнем регистре.

```
Function Transliteration(ByVal A As String) As String
    A = A.ToLower          'Удалить, если нужен верхний регистр'
    A = A.Replace("a", "a")
    A = A.Replace("б", "b")
    A = A.Replace("в", "v")
    A = A.Replace("г", "g")
    A = A.Replace("д", "d")
    A = A.Replace("е", "e")
    A = A.Replace("ё", "jo")
    A = A.Replace("ж", "zh")
    A = A.Replace("з", "z")
    A = A.Replace("и", "i")
    A = A.Replace("й", "j")
    A = A.Replace("к", "k")
    A = A.Replace("л", "l")
    A = A.Replace("м", "m")
    A = A.Replace("н", "n")
    A = A.Replace("о", "o")
    A = A.Replace("п", "p")
    A = A.Replace("р", "r")
    A = A.Replace("с", "s")
    A = A.Replace("т", "t")
    A = A.Replace("у", "u")
    A = A.Replace("ф", "f")
    A = A.Replace("х", "h")
    A = A.Replace("ц", "c")
    A = A.Replace("ч", "ch")
    A = A.Replace("ш", "sh")
    A = A.Replace("щ", "sz")
    A = A.Replace("ь", "'")
    A = A.Replace("ъ", "#")
    A = A.Replace("ы", "y")
    A = A.Replace("э", "eh")
    A = A.Replace("ю", "ju")
    A = A.Replace("я", "ja")
    'A = A.Replace("А", "A")   А в верхнем регистре'
    Return (A)
End Function
```

Использование:

```
Dim Slovo As String = Transliteration("слово")
```

Comment: Ой, как неэффективно!

Надо перебрать все символы строки и для каждого сделать Select case, который будет транслироваться в код со сложностью log(n). При этом надо перед транслированием проверять регистр каждого символа, запоминать в локальную переменную, а после транслирования восстанаваливать сохранённый регистр.

Comment: По моему мой способ эффективнее, вся сложность/неэффективность моего способа состоит только в том, что букв в русском алфавите 33, а символов 66, и для каждого нужна замена.

Answer (score 1):

1. Для веб-приложения можно пользовать [Google Transliterate API](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/language/transliterate/overview.html)
2. Для обычного приложения нужно писать самому на основе [таблиц транслитерации](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Comment: Если постараться, то Google Transliterate API можно и на не веб приложении реализовать, правда нужен будет доступ к интеренету вроде...
А VB.NET это не веб - приложения!